# Custom DNS server for Azure Staging environment

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have an Azure Web App, and I'm using deployment slots to smoketest my service in production before deploying. I want to test this service with my production client exe that doesn't allow users to change the URL of the service they are hitting.

So what I'd like to do is have a custom DNS server that I can point my PC at that will resolve prod.mydomain.com as staging-prod.mydomain.com so that I can run against staging by only changing my DNS server. This DNS server would ideally be publicly accessible to allow my test team in a different company to test staging before deployment.

Is there any support for hosting this within Azure? I've tried looking at DNS zones, but they don't seem to offer the features I need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a normal DNS server which supports Domain Alias record.

Create a DNAME record named prod.mydomain.com and point it to staging-prod.mydomain.com.

If you want to access the domain world wide, then you need to purchase the domain and configure the NS records and point it to your own DNS server. After that your need to wait several hours so that the NS record can be replicated over the world.

Here is a screenshot of my lab:

[image]